# Koenig lookup for arguments

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

Is idea of Koenig lookup for arguments a bad thing?

With ADL we have:

```
namespace foo
{
    struct bar {};
    void baz(bar);
}

baz(foo::bar());
```

And why we don't have something like:

```
namespace foo
{
  struct bar {};
  void baz(bar);
} // namespace foo

foo::baz(bar());
```

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of ["Why was ADL invented?"](/questions/4276772/why-was-argument-dependent-lookup-invented?rq=1)

Comment: @Rhymoid, if not for the second question, I'd have said yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focusing on the non-duplicate part, why not `foo::baz(bar());`? The simple reason is that in C++, the parse tree is always processed bottom to top. Name lookup of a function name depends on the function arguments, not the other way around, just like overload resolution depends on the argument types and not the return type.

Answer (score 4):

> Is idea of Koenig lookup for arguments a bad thing?

Absolutely not. It allows placement of non-member API where it belongs: the same namespace as your type; which it does without forcing users to be aware of the namespace when invoking functions.
Consider how convenient it is to write `sort(begin(vec), end(vec));` as opposed to `std::sort(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec));`

It's also a must have when you overload operators.

> And why we don't have something like:
>
> ```
> namespace foo
> {
>   struct bar {};
>   void baz(bar);
> } // namespace foo
>
> foo::baz(bar());
> ```

Because it's easily more ambiguous than the opposite. What if `foo::baz` is overloaded for `bar` in different namespaces? You'd make it impossible to call it with the other `bar` without fully qualifying it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is idea of Koenig lookup for arguments a bad thing?

Not at all. Consider about the scenario of operator overloading, [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) makes it possible to use operators defined in a different namespace.

```
namespace foo
{
    struct bar {};
    bar operator+ (const bar& lhs, const bar&rhs);
}
```

with ADL, we can write

```
foo::bar b1, b2;
auto b3 = b1 + b2; // natural as operator
```

without ADL, we have to write

```
auto b3 = foo::operator+(b1, b2); // unnatural
```

As a sidenote, all the overloaded operators of STL is defined in namespace `std`. Without ADL, we even could call them straightforward.

Furthermore, without ADL, it'll be challenging for template.

```
template <typename T>
T add(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
    return What_Namespace::operator+(lhs, rhs); // how to deduce the name of namespace?
}
```